# How to use Time Machine to back up a partitioned drive?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, ssd, partition

My MBP was originally a single SSD partition, which I backed up with Time Machine to an external USB HD.

I created a new partition on the SSD for Yosemite, and am running the MBP on 10.10, although my apps and my work docs are on the original partition.

I would like to continue to use TimeMachine to back up the original HD with my documents and such, so if Yosemite fails or corrupts the HD, I can buy a new HD and restore the Mavericks HD to it.

How can this be done?

Failing keeping it separate, could I at least set up TM on a new disk to back up both partitions?